# Finding the roots of a complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I was solving practice problems for my upcoming midterm and however I got stuck with this question type.

It is asking me to find all roots and then sketch it.

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{1/2}$

How do we proceed?

Comment: Try writing it in the form $re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Substitute $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}i}=a+bi$$ then you have to solve $$a^2-b^2=1$$ and $$\sqrt{3}=2ab$$

Comment: And $a^2+b^2=2$

Comment: Where come this from?

Comment: Taking modulus of each side

Comment: $$(a+bi)^2=a^2-b^2+2abi$$

Comment: $|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2$ and $|1+i\sqrt{3}|=2$

Comment: You don't need this step.

Answer (score 0):

$1+i\sqrt{3}=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}={(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}})}^2$ thus the roots are $\pm \sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}=\pm(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

General way to find the roots of $z=a+ib$

Let $\delta=x+iy$ a root of $z$. Then $\delta^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy=a+ib$ and thus $x^2-y^2=a$ and $2xy=b$. Using modulus we obtain : $|z|=|\delta|^2\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

> This provides the following system:
>   $$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=a ,\\x^2+y^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\\2xy=b \end{cases}.$$

The first two equations gives $$x^2=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}$$ $$ y^2=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}.$$

> $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}}, y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}}.$$

The last equation can be used to find the sign of $x$ and $y$. In your example $2xy=\sqrt{3}>0$ which means that $sign(x)=sign(y)$ and thus we have to choose $x>0$ and $y>0$, or $x<0$ and $y<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the roots be of the form $u+iv$. You need to solve

$$(u+iv)^2=1+i\sqrt3.$$

As $(u+iv)^2=u^2-v^2+2iuv$, by identification

$$\begin{cases}u^2-v^2=1,\\2uv=\sqrt3\end{cases}.$$

Now multiplying the first by $u^2$,

$$u^4-u^2v^2=u^4-\frac34=u^2$$ is a biquadratic equation. We obtain

$$u^2=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+3}}{2}=\frac32,-\frac12$$

and the only real roots are

$$u=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2},$$ corresponding to $$v=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

---

Final check:

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)^2=\frac32-\frac12+2i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$